# git alias taking all given arguments

Tags: git, aliases

What I've been trying to do is make a git alias so that `git heroku Fix that bug` will run:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Fix that bug"
git push heroku master
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
heroku = "!f() { git add .; git commit -m \"$@\"; git push heroku master; }; f"
```

seems to have been the most promising so far, though with this if I do `git heroku test test`, it tells me that `error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

I've also tried some other ones like `!sh -c 'git add ...' -` but that didn't work too well either.

Anyone know how to fix this? (and why that message is occuring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you pass the log message as a single, *quoted* string. Even though you could get way with a list of unquoted words in most cases using

```
git commit -m "$*"
```

eventually you *will* try to use a commit message like

```
git heroku Replace * with #
```

and you're going to get a list of file names in your commit message. Just get used to

```
git heroku "Replace * with #"
```

and define your alias as

```
heroku = '!f() { git add .; git commit -m "$1"; git push heroic master; }; f'
```

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for the reply, and good points. What does `$*` do?

Comment: Anyways, the `$*` did work, so thanks, but I might consider doing the single quoted string thing, it sounds like a better solution. Thanks again, couldn't +1 though, sorry; not enough rep